# Why doesn't a loader change its source on a state change if it has a default state specified?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML `Loader`, which can have two states. Depending on the state, different content is to be loaded.

```
Loader
{
    id: mainLoader
    anchors.fill: parent

    state: "state1"

    states:
    [
        State
        {
            name: "state1"
            PropertyChanges {target: mainLoader; source: "page1.qml"}
        },

        State
        {
            name: "state2"
            PropertyChanges {target: mainLoader; source: "page2.qml"}
        }
    ]
}
```

There are two buttons elsewhere in the application, which have `onClicked: mainLoader.state = "state1"` and `onClicked: mainLoader.state = "state2"`, respectively.

Although the state does indeed get changed (verified by printing a debug message in the `StateChangeScript`), it is always page 1 which remains loaded at all times, page 2 never appeares.

What I don't understand, are the following:

- if I don't assign a default state (so I remove `state: "state1"`), the two buttons work, and both pages are displayed correctly according to which button I pressed. Of course, before any button is pressed, the Loader is empty.
- if I add `asynchronous: true` to the loader, the two buttons work fine.

There are several simple, but not very elegant solutions, for example

- just assign a default `source` instead of a default `state`. I don't like it as then I'll have 3 states, including the empty one, and I need to refer to the state of the loader at other places.
- stick to asynchronous operation.
- use `Component.onCompleted: state = "state1"` instead of `state: "state1"`

However, I would like to understand what lies behind this behavior. I know that properties are not filled in the order they are written in the qml files, but by the time I press the buttons, the Loader was already completed a long time ago.

Comment: I've tested that in Qt 5.7, Windows 10 x64 and it works like a charm. What Qt version do you use? And please, provide all the suitable code. Try to come to mcve and may be this problem will be solved before you post a comment =).

Comment: @folibis : There is no other code in the `Loader`, and it is nowhere else referred to (yet) besides the buttons which do nothing but change the sate. I guess the content which is to be loaded does not matter. I use Qt 5.5.1 on Debian, thank you for the test, I'll try it on a different system and with a different Qt version. Until then, I'll stick to using `Component.onCompleted`

Comment: I have issues with setting `source` property trough `state`s. It seems to be same issue as you have. Whenever I set `source` of the loader, it restore `source` value to default and then set it to new value. it causes bad behaviour.